# Module object has no attribute 'argpaser' ---- Python

Tags: python, import, module, argparse, google-prediction

I'm having an error on a python file. What it does is to get acces to an specific google API. OAuth2.0. But that's not the wrong part. The wrong part takes part of argparse (Retriving arguments from console by adding --something="").

Here's my code:

```
import argparse
import os
import pprint
import sys
import time
import httplib2

from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import file
from oauth2client import tools 
from oauth2client import client


# Time to wait (in seconds) between successive checks of training status.
SLEEP_TIME = 10


# Declare command-line flags.
argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
argparser.add_argument('object_name',
                     help='Full Google Storage path of csv data (ex bucket/object)')
argparser.add_argument('id',
                     help='Model Id of your choosing to name trained model')
#argparser.add_argument('action');


def print_header(line):
  '''Format and print header block sized to length of line'''
  header_str = '='
  header_line = header_str * len(line)
  print '\n' + header_line
  print line
  print header_line


def main(argv):

  parent_parsers = [tools.argparser]
  parent_parsers.extend(parents)
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=doc,
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
        parents=parent_parsers)
  flags = parser.parse_args(argv[1:])

  scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction'

  client_secrets = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                'client_secrets.json')
  flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(client_secrets,
      scope=scope,
      message=tools.message_if_missing(client_secrets))

  storage = file.Storage('prediction.dat')
  credentials = storage.get()

  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
    http = credentials.authorize(http = httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('prediction', 'v1.6', http=http)


  try:
    papi = service.trainedmodels()
    print_header('Fetching list of first ten models')
    result = papi.list(maxResults=10).execute()
    print 'List results:'
    pprint.pprint(result)

  except client.AccessTokenRefreshError:
    print ("The credentials have been revoked or expired, please re-run"
      "the application to re-authorize")


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(sys.argv)
```

On this line--> `parent_parsers = [tools.argparser]` I'm having that error:

> line 75, in main
>       parent_parsers = [tools.argparser]
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'argparser'

The tools.py file is that one:

```
import BaseHTTPServer
import argparse
import httplib2
import logging
import os
import socket
import sys
import webbrowser

from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import file
from oauth2client import util

try:
  from urlparse import parse_qsl
except ImportError:
  from cgi import parse_qsl

_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0

To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
found at:

   %s

with information from the APIs Console <https://code.google.com/apis/console>.

"""

# run_parser is an ArgumentParser that contains command-line options expected
# by tools.run(). Pass it in as part of the 'parents' argument to your own
# ArgumentParser.
argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
argparser.add_argument('--auth_host_name', default='localhost',
                        help='Hostname when running a local web server.')
argparser.add_argument('--noauth_local_webserver', action='store_true',
                        default=False, help='Do not run a local web server.')
argparser.add_argument('--auth_host_port', default=[8080, 8090], type=int,
                        nargs='*', help='Port web server should listen on.')
argparser.add_argument('--logging_level', default='ERROR',
                        choices=['DEBUG', 'INFO', 'WARNING', 'ERROR',
                                 'CRITICAL'],
                        help='Set the logging level of detail.')


class ClientRedirectServer(BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer):
  """A server to handle OAuth 2.0 redirects back to localhost.

  Waits for a single request and parses the query parameters
  into query_params and then stops serving.
  """
  query_params = {}


class ClientRedirectHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
  """A handler for OAuth 2.0 redirects back to localhost.

  Waits for a single request and parses the query parameters
  into the servers query_params and then stops serving.
  """

  def do_GET(s):
    """Handle a GET request.

    Parses the query parameters and prints a message
    if the flow has completed. Note that we can't detect
    if an error occurred.
    """
    s.send_response(200)
    s.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
    s.end_headers()
    query = s.path.split('?', 1)[-1]
    query = dict(parse_qsl(query))
    s.server.query_params = query
    s.wfile.write("<html><head><title>Authentication Status</title></head>")
    s.wfile.write("<body><p>The authentication flow has completed.</p>")
    s.wfile.write("</body></html>")

  def log_message(self, format, *args):
    """Do not log messages to stdout while running as command line program."""
    pass


@util.positional(3)
def run_flow(flow, storage, flags, http=None):

  logging.getLogger().setLevel(getattr(logging, flags.logging_level))
  if not flags.noauth_local_webserver:
    success = False
    port_number = 0
    for port in flags.auth_host_port:
      port_number = port
      try:
        httpd = ClientRedirectServer((flags.auth_host_name, port),
                                     ClientRedirectHandler)
      except socket.error, e:
        pass
      else:
        success = True
        break
    flags.noauth_local_webserver = not success
    if not success:
      print 'Failed to start a local webserver listening on either port 8080'
      print 'or port 9090. Please check your firewall settings and locally'
      print 'running programs that may be blocking or using those ports.'
      print
      print 'Falling back to --noauth_local_webserver and continuing with',
      print 'authorization.'
      print

  if not flags.noauth_local_webserver:
    oauth_callback = 'http://%s:%s/' % (flags.auth_host_name, port_number)
  else:
    oauth_callback = client.OOB_CALLBACK_URN
  flow.redirect_uri = oauth_callback
  authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()

  if not flags.noauth_local_webserver:
    webbrowser.open(authorize_url, new=1, autoraise=True)
    print 'Your browser has been opened to visit:'
    print
    print '    ' + authorize_url
    print
    print 'If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this'
    print 'application with the command-line parameter '
    print
    print '  --noauth_local_webserver'
    print
  else:
    print 'Go to the following link in your browser:'
    print
    print '    ' + authorize_url
    print

  code = None
  if not flags.noauth_local_webserver:
    httpd.handle_request()
    if 'error' in httpd.query_params:
      sys.exit('Authentication request was rejected.')
    if 'code' in httpd.query_params:
      code = httpd.query_params['code']
    else:
      print 'Failed to find "code" in the query parameters of the redirect.'
      sys.exit('Try running with --noauth_local_webserver.')
  else:
    code = raw_input('Enter verification code: ').strip()

  try:
    credential = flow.step2_exchange(code, http=http)
  except client.FlowExchangeError, e:
    sys.exit('Authentication has failed: %s' % e)

  storage.put(credential)
  credential.set_store(storage)
  print 'Authentication successful.'

  return credential


def message_if_missing(filename):
  """Helpful message to display if the CLIENT_SECRETS file is missing."""

  return _CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE % filename

try:
  from old_run import run
except ImportError:
  def run(*args, **kwargs):
    raise NotImplementedError(
        'The gflags library must be installed to use tools.run(). '
        'Please install gflags or preferrably switch to using '
        'tools.run_flow().')
```

I don't understand the meaning of the error, it may be an import issue but I don't know.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the oauth tools are setup properly:

```
python setup_oauth2client.py install
```

it's in the base directory